# Browser not showing math symbols when I am visiting certain websites

Tags: mathjax, edge

[image]Okk so here is my issue I visited the stack math website and all the mathematical symbols were replaced with probably some tex code or something else that I don't know of I tried my best to search it but could not find any solution that I was capable of executing.

Comment: This is a question about MathJaX, which is a javascript program that is inspired by LaTeX but not actually LaTeX, so expertise in TeX doesn't often help with questions like this, so it's off-topic here.

Comment: okk gotcha but since I am new here so I did not know a lot of terms also don't understand difference about some terms as you mentioned but still thanks.

Comment: Not a problem - we try to be helpful here but the truth is that you're going to get better help on this elsewhere.  You might try instead searching among the [questions tagged with mathjax on Stack Overflow](//stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathjax), or in the official [mathjax-users](https://groups.google.com/d/forum/mathjax-users) Google group.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the mathjax math renderer, see, for example, [How do I change Math Renderer for MathJax?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30859/how-do-i-change-math-renderer-for-mathjax). And in this special case that all the formulas are displayed as source code, I recommend you to [clear all the cookie](https://www.lifewire.com/clear-cookies-for-one-site-4587347) about MSE first.